# Is there any better way to define relational operators in C++ pre C++20?

Tags: c++, operators, c++17, comparison-operators

It gets pretty tedious for me to write code like

```
class date {
private: 
    int day, year, month;
    int comp(const date & Other) const;
public:
    date(int D, int Y, int M) : day (D), year (Y), month (M)  {}

    friend bool operator==(const date & L, const date & R) { return L.comp(R) == 0 ; }
    friend bool operator!=(const date & L, const date & R) { return L.comp(R) != 0 ; }
    friend bool operator> (const date & L, const date & R) { return L.comp(R) > 0 ; }
    friend bool operator>=(const date & L, const date & R) { return L.comp(R) >= 0 ; }
    friend bool operator< (const date & L, const date & R) { return L.comp(R) < 0 ; }
    friend bool operator<=(const date & L, const date & R) { return L.comp(R) <= 0 ; }
}
```

All that relational operators stuff is boilerplate (same for every single class that needs them). There must *surely* be a better way to do all this. I know that C++ 20 offers the spaceship operator, but I don't have that. So my question is this: How do I avoid this boilerplate code using older than C++ 20 features?

Comment: If you're okay with sacrificing *a little bit* of performance (for example, making twice as many comparisons), CRTP (curiously recurring template pattern) may work here.

Comment: Boost will help https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/utility/operators.htm

Comment: Templated operators? So you only need to implement compare? Might give really bad error messages

Comment: "*There must surely be a better way to do all this.*" Nonsense. If there was a better way, C++20 wouldn't have had to *create* the better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Boost.Operators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) (or implement such a thing yourself), but you'd still have to write two functions:

```
class date : public totally_ordered<date> {
private: 
    int day, year, month;
    int comp(const date & Other) ;
public:
    date(int D, int Y, int M) : day (D), year (Y), month (M)  {}

    friend bool operator==(const date & L, const date & R) { return L.comp(R) == 0 ; }
    friend bool operator< (const date & L, const date & R) { return L.comp(R) < 0 ; }
}
```

Note that you generally don't want to use the pattern of defining `==` in terms of a three-way ordering since `==` can be much more efficient in general (e.g. consider the case of strings where you know differently-sized strings are unequal right away, but you don't know what the result of `compare()` would be without actually comparing an arbitrarily large number of characters).

Note also that a general problem with this approach is deciding whether `x <= y` is defined as `!(y < x)` or `x < y || x == y`. Most library solutions choose the former (fewer comparisons), though this gives the wrong answer on partial orders - which was part of the motivation for `<=>` to begin with. Boost.Operators addresses this by also having a `partially_ordered<T>` which correctly defines `<=` in terms of both operations.

---

> There must surely be a better way to do all this.

As [Nicol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59504339/is-there-any-better-way-to-define-relational-operators-in-c-pre-c20#comment105181416_59504339) says, that's why we added `<=>`:

```
class date {
private: 
    int year, month, day; // NB: I reordered these
public:
    friend auto operator<=>(const date&, const date&) = default;
};
```

Comment: What exactly is a partial order?

Comment: @JohnJenkins The simplest answer is: an order which is not total, which does not satisfy trichotomy -- given a pair of elements, there might not be an ordering between them. For example, subset for sets. `{1} < {1, 2}` and `{1, 2} > {2}` but if you compare `{1}` to `{2}`, it's neither `<` nor `>` nor `==`.